# Finding a Projective resolution of an element of a Short Exact Sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity
If $$ 0\longrightarrow L \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow 0$$ is a short exact sequence of R modules. 
Now given two  projective resolutions of $L$ and $N$; by Horseshoe lemma I can find a projective resolution of $M$.

My question is if I have $\textbf{finite}$ projective resolutions of both $M$ and $N$ then can I construct a projective resolution of $L$?

My attempt (or guess): Let $\textbf{P.}$ $\longrightarrow M$ and $\textbf{Q.}$ $\longrightarrow N$ be the projective resolutions.

Then for $f : M \longrightarrow N$  I have a chain map lift from $\textbf{P.}$ $\longrightarrow \textbf{Q.}$

So my guess is if I take the mapping cone $\textbf{P}_{n-1} \oplus \textbf{Q}_n$

It might give me a projective resolution for $L$, but I am unable to prove my claim.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing to do is to alter $P$ with $Q$ in order to make the chain map $P\to Q$ degreewise surjective. Then its kernel is degreewise projective and is an exact complex except in degree $0$ where the homology is $L$ (by the long exact sequence of homology)

Comment: Alright so if I have understood correctly what you are saying is take $P_{0} \oplus Q_{1} \longrightarrow Q_{0}$ a surjection, let's take $K_{0}$ as the kernel of the surjection and take the resolution $..\longrightarrow P_{1} \oplus Q_{2} \longrightarrow K_{0}$ Since both P. and Q. are finite this resolution will terminate at point.

Comment: No, $P_1\oplus Q_2\to P_0\oplus Q_1$ does not a priori factor through $K_0$, and is not necessarily surjective onto $K_0$. What I mean is : there is a resolution $P'$ (which can be obtained from $P$ by tweeking it by $Q$ : it starts as $P_2 \oplus Q_1\oplus Q_2 \to P_1\oplus Q_0\oplus Q_1 \to P_0\oplus Q_0$)  such that the natural chain map $P'\to Q$ is degreewise surjective. In this case, its kernel $K$ is a projective resolution of $L$ (and if everything is finite, then this one is finite as well)

Comment: Thank you Max I got it. It was really a great help. :)